# Why $a^{n-1}\cdot(1-b)-b^{n-1}\cdot(1-a) = a^n-b^n$

Tags: polynomials

How to simplify from

$a^{n-1}\cdot(1-b)-b^{n-1}\cdot(1-a)$ to

$a^n-b^n$?

I am very sorry for forgetting given $a=\cfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ , $b=\cfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

[the book shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO2SS.jpg)

Comment: Are you assuming $a+b=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=0,b=2,n=3$ we have:

$$a^{n-1}\cdot(1-b)-b^{n-1}\cdot(1-a)=-4\neq -8=a^n-b^n$$

This disproved the statement.

---

Update:

Let $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},b=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ we have:

\begin{align}
&~~~~~~a^{n-1}\cdot(1-b)-b^{n-1}\cdot(1-a)\\
&=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\\
&=a^n-b^n
\end{align}

Comment: I am very sorry for forgetting given a , b condition

Comment: @吳柏亞 I made some updates $\dots$

Comment: Thank you so much